# Filter using multiple condition in flutter

Tags: flutter

Here is my sample json

```
[
  {
    "id": 129,
    "type": 3,
    "is_default": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 130,
    "type": 1,
    "is_default": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 131,
    "type": 5,
    "is_default": 1
  }
]
```

i need to filter the values of type 1 and and 3 and also default is 1

so i doing like this

```
 value = data.where((i) => i.type == 1 || i.type == 3).toList();
```

and doing another loop

```
finalvalue = value.where((i) => i.is_default == 1).toList();
```

SO if there is no default in any array i need to set first array to default and then filter once more so how to do it in an efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Make this:

```dart
finalValue = data.where((i) => i.type == 1 || i.type == 3)
            .where((i) => i.is_default == 1)
            .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are free to do this:

```
final finalvalue = value.where((i) => i.is_default == 1 && (i.type == 1 || i.type == 3)).toList();
```